# ubuntu desktop doesn't show icons

Tags: ubuntu-10.04

There are files on the desktop but they don't show up. You can open a file browser and go to the desktop and see the files.

Right clicking on the desktop does nothing.

Trying to move a file on to the desktop from another folder does nothing.

Any idea?

Turned the box back on... now there is the desktop and the mouse. Nothing else. It responds to pressing the power button and the mouse moves.

Comment: What is you frontend? Kde, gnome, xfce, ...?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check if nautilus is running. Just start it like:

```
nautilus &
```

and the icons will show up.

If you get "Command Not Found", check your path and/or (re-)install it.